# Convolution of two continuously distributed random variables (graphically and via formula)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> Let the random variable $X$ be uniformly distributed on the interval
> $[0, a]$. Let the random variable $Y$ be uniformly distributed on the
> interval $[0, b]$. Let $a$ and $b$ be parameters with $0 < a < b$.
> Furthermore let $X$ and $Y$ be independent. Determine the distribution
> function of $X + Y$.

I know that the sum of two independent uniformly distributed random variables will have a [Trapezoidal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_distribution). I tried in two ways:

$(1)$ **Graphical Approach**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#/media/File:Convolution_of_box_signal_with_itself2.gif

I imagined one of the rectangles hovering over the $x$-axis from left to right and looked at the yellow area (cf. Wikipedia animation).  I experimented with $a=2$ and $b=3$ and got a trapezoid given by the points $(-2,0)$, $(-1,1/3)$, $(0,2/3)$, $(1,2/3)$, $(2,1/3)$, $(3,0)$.

[image]

It unfortunately has area 2, so it can't be right.

$(2)$ Approach using the convolution formula.

We have $X\sim \mathcal{U}([0,a])$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{U}([0,b])$ with densities $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{a}\chi_{\{0\leq x\leq a\}}(x)$  and $f_Y(x)=\frac{1}{b}\chi_{\{0\leq x\leq b\}}(x)$, where $\chi$ is the indicator function. The formula now says: $$f_{X+Y}(t)=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(s)f_Y(t-s)\, \mathrm{d}s=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}\chi_{\{0\leq s\leq a\}}(s)\frac{1}{b}\chi_{\{0\leq t-s\leq b\}}(t-s)\, \mathrm{d}s=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ab}\underbrace{\chi_{\{0\leq s\leq a\}}(s)\cdot \chi_{\{0\leq t-s\leq b\}}(t-s)}_{=???}\, \mathrm{d}s$$ I don't know how to deal with the indicator functions. This approach thus found it's end aswell.

**How can I solve these problems?**

Comment: The height of the trapezoid should be $\frac13$, not $\frac23$.

Comment: The product of the indicator functions of intervals $I_1$ and $I_2$ is the indicator function of $I_1\cap I_2$.

Comment: Why $1/3$? At $x=0$, we have a rectangle (hovering from left to right) that takes up $2/3$ of the other one. Second question: But what about the different "inputs" of the indicator functions. We have $s$ and $t-s$.

Comment: The height of the longer interval is $\frac13$, and the area under the shorter interval is $1$. The $\frac13$ times the $1$ area gives $\frac13$. As far as the inputs, they just shift the intervals.

Comment: What's wrong with my sketch? (https://gyazo.com/3bb19908ad233681c7cf2280f7992086), and concerning the intervals, I have to intersect $0\leq s\leq a$ and $t-b\leq s\leq t$, so integrate between the lines $t-b$ and $t$ between $0$ and $a$. Is that a double integral?

Comment: You **multiply** the functions and integrate. That would be $\frac12\cdot\frac13\cdot2=\frac13$.

Comment: Oh ... I see. Thank you.